# How to unit test js asynch with jasmine mocking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

I am fairly new to JS and I was having some issues with testing asynch methods with jasmine mocking.

Here is the class I want to test:

```
 test.factory('service', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
     var _func = function(varB, successCallback, errorCallback) {

         //Sanity check on input
         if (isNaN(varB)) {
             errorCallback('varB has to be a number');
             return;
         }

         if (parseInt(varB) < 0) {
             errorCallback('varB count has to be positive');
             return;
         }

         $http.get('http://www.test.com').then(function(response) {
             var data = angular.copy(response.data);
             if (successCallback) {
                 successCallback(data);
             }
         }, function(errorResponse) {
             if (errorCallback) {
                 errorCallback(errorResponse.data);
             }
         });
     };

     return {
         func: function(varB) {
             return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                 _func(varB, resolve, reject);
             });
         }
     };
 }]);
```

One of the tests:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
     service = $injector.get(
         'service');
     $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
 }));

 it('should use the rejection handler if varB is in invalid format',
     function() {
         var successHandler = jasmine.createSpy('success');
         var failHandler = jasmine.createSpy('fail');
         service.func('abc').then(successHandler, failHandler);
         expect(successHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
         expect(failHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith('varB has to be a number');
     }
 );
```

The line in the test:
    `expect(failHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith('varB has to be a number');` never gets executed for some reason. I even tried putting debug statements in the service class to see if the methods were reached and they were getting reached. But the mock was not able to detect that the callback was called with the given argument.

Would be great to get some insights! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the solution.

Got hints [here](https://brianmcd.com/post/2014-3-27-angular-testing-tip/).

So the thing is to add a rootScope injection. It worked after that! :)

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
     service = $injector.get(
         'service');
     $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
 }));

 it('should use the rejection handler if varB is in invalid format',
     function() {
         var successHandler = jasmine.createSpy('success');
         var failHandler = jasmine.createSpy('fail');
         service.func('abc').then(successHandler, failHandler);
         $rootScope.$digest();
         expect(successHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
         expect(failHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith('varB has to be a number');
     }
 );
```

Comment: but service.func is still async and can be ran for(for example) 1 minute, so this test is not bulletproof